# Do I need transactions/locks for this concurrent update scenario in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, concurrency, transactions, locks

I am wondering whether I really do need transactions/locks in the following scenario. I can carry out 3 operations which might be concurrent in any number of them (i.e. I could have two Task 1 running and three Task 2 running):

Task 1:

```
select distinct count(some_id) as my_counter from table_1;
update table_2 set counter = my_counter;
```

Task 2:

```
insert into table_1 ...;
update table_2 set counter = counter + 1;
```

Task 3:

```
delete from table_1 where id = ...;
update table_2 set counter = counter - 1;
```

How should I implement the above being sure that I will never corrupt table_2's field `counter`?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few points:

- In any case you need to enclose the two statements of each task in a transaction.
- I think you need serializable transaction isolation level. Anything less will not do. For example using "repeatable read" task 1 might set table_2.counter to a stale value.
- You need to always access table_1 before table_2. This will ensure a consistent lock-ordering preventing deadlocks.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `TRIGGER` for Task 2,3. it locks you tables in appropriate way.  for `Task 1` you should use `XLOCK` for row lock in your transaction

Comment: I would not say that a trigger does any locking by itself at all. I don't think this answer is correct.